# POSIX: abcdef to ab bc cd de ef

Tags: shell, awk, sed, posix

Using POSIX `sed` or `awk`, I would like to duplicate every second character in every pair of neighboring characters and list every newly-formed pair on a new line.

example.txt:

```
abcd 10001.
```

Expected result:

```
ab
bc
cd
d 
 1
10
00
00
01
1.
```

So far, this is what I have (N.B. omit "--posix" if on macOS). For some reason, adding a literal newline character   before `\2` does not produce the expected result. Removing the first group and using `\1` has the same effect. What am I missing?

```
sed --posix -E -e 's/(.)(.)/&\2\
/g' example.txt

abb
cdd
100
000
1..
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have both `--posix` (a GNU-only option) and `-E` options since `-E` enables EREs in GNU sed and OSX/BSD sed but EREs aren't supported by POSIX. Also don't assume that if you run your script with `--posix` that it's only using syntax that's specified by POSIX. All it means is that non-POSIX extensions are disabled but it might still be relying on behavior that simply isn't defined by POSIX and so it won't work in other POSIX seds. Basically, if you're doing any more than `s/old/new/g` on a single line of input or output then you're probably using non-portable constructs

Comment: I didn't realize just how much portable awk is, compared to sed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
$ echo "abcd 10001." | awk '{for(i=1;i<length($0);i++) print substr($0,i,2)}'
ab
bc
cd
d 
 1
10
00
00
01
1.
```

Comment: I can't imagine why anyone would downvote as this is the robust, portable solution that'll work using any awk in any shell for any input on all UNIX systems.

Answer (score 5):

You may use

```
sed --posix -e 's/./&\
&/g' example.txt | sed '1d;$d'
```

The first `sed` command finds every char in the string and replaces with the same char, then a newline and then the same char again. Since it replaces first and last chars, the first and last resulting lines must be removed, which is achieved with `sed '1d;$d'`.

Had `sed` supported lookarounds, one could have used `(?!^).(?!$)` (any char but not at the start or end of string) and the last `sed` command would not have been necessary, but it is not possible with `sed`. You could use it in `perl` though, `perl -pe 's/(?!^).(?!$)/$&\n$&/g' example.txt` (see [demo online](https://ideone.com/BTDnoz), `$&` in the RHS is the same as `&` placeholder in `sed`, the whole match value).

Comment: No need for another `sed '1d;$d'`. You can "dot it" `&g; s/^..//; s/..$//'`

Answer (score 5):

With GNU `awk` could you please try following. Written and tested with shown samples and tested it in link
https://ideone.com/qahp0S

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=""
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=(NF-1);i++){
    print $i$(i+1)
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** setting field separator as NULL in the BEGIN section of program for all lines here. Then in main program running a for loop which runs from 1st field to till 2nd last field. In that loop's each iteration printing current and next field.

Answer (score 4):

Using same routine, it can be done in `bash` itself:

```
s='abcd 10001.'

for((i=0; i<${#s}-1; i++)); do echo "${s:i:2}"; done
```

```
ab
bc
cd
d
 1
10
00
00
01
1.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, a single `sed` consisting of 3 substitutions:

```
$ echo "abcd 10001." | sed 's/./&&/g;s/\(^.\|.$\)//g;s/../&\n/g'
```

The first part duplicates all characters, the second part removes the first and last character, the third part adds a newline character after each character-pair.

If you want to be POSIX compliant you have to do:

```
$ echo "abcd 10001." | sed -e  's/./&&/g' -e 's/^.//g' -e 's/.$//g' -e 's/../&\n/g'
```

Here we had to add an extra one as the expression `\(^.\|.$)` is an ERE and posix sed only accepts a BRE

Comment: just a detail, may be use `echo -n ...` to be compatible with OP case and not have the newline get and managed/output by *sed* ? (the problem does not occurs with *awk*)

Comment: @bruno In Posix, there is no option `-n`

Answer (score 0):

Process substitution isn't specified by POSIX. The POSIX requirement was only specified for `awk` and `sed`, so maybe the next solution is acceptable:

```
paste -d '\0' <(echo; fold -w1 example.txt) <(fold -w1 example.txt) | grep ..
```

or

```
while read -n1 ch; do
   printf "%s\n%s" "${ch}" "${ch}"
done < example.txt | grep ..
```

or

```
sed 's/./&&/g;s/.//' example.txt | grep -o ..
```

Comment: `paste -d ""` is a GNUism. POSIX would be `paste  -d '\0'` for the same function. You then need to delete first and line with `| sed -e '1d;$d'` to get the OPs example. Creative though!

Comment: @dawg I edited my answer (added \0). I delete the first/last line by grepping lines with two characters. The <(..) is not POSIX, so the first solution was just for fun.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/.\(.\)/&\n\1/;/../P;D' file
```

Replace the first two characters by the first two characters, a newline and the second character.

Print the first line if it is two characters long, delete the first line and repeat.

Alternative, more long winded:

```
sed -E ':a;s/^(([^\n]{2}\n)*[^\n])([^\n])([^\n])/\1\3\n\3\4/;ta' file
```

Or, with no hardcoded new line:

```
sed -E '/.../{G;s/^(.(.))(.*)(.)/\1\4\2\3/;P;D}' file
```

Lastly:

```
sed 's/./&\n&/g;s/^..\|..$/g' file
```